# Files showing as deleted after git clone

Tags: git

I will try to explain my problem as accurately as I can.

I cloned my project for the first time with following command

> git clone --config core.filemode=false --recursive [code_location] [project]

This works without and error message. Then I switch to my project folder and do a

> git status

That's when it shows all the files as deleted and then all project subfolders aa untracked files.

Can anyone tell me what the issue is?

Comment: Is the parent (or any of it's parents) folder also a git repo? Sounds like there is one somewhere between drive root and your clone location.

Comment: I am not  sure, but I don't think it has a parent directory.

Comment: Don't use `--config core.filemode=false`. Git will probe your system's behavior and set `core.filemode` correctly *for your particular system* on its own; you should only override this in some very special cases. That's probably not causing this problem, though. I think it more likely that you have hit a bug with `--recursive`: try cloning without that flag, too.

Comment: Note that the `--recursive` flag simply directs Git to run `git submodule update --init --recursive` after the initial clone. However, it's been optimized recently to try to make it go fast. This introduced some bugs in some versions of Git. If that's the problem, upgrading to yet a newer version of Git, or downgrading to an *older* version, may make the `--recursive` mode work again for you.

Comment: Unless you are cloning at the root of your harddive you have a parent folder (just `cd ..`). Check if any parent folder has a `.git` folder - if they do, that's your issue

Comment: I am not sure if the issue was with --recursive or not but I was working with git version 2.29.2.2 and when I reverted to 2.15.1.windows.2 I do not have this issue anymore. I was not comfortable with experimenting in case I broke something in the master branch, so I simply reverted to the older version. Thanks everyone for your inputs but in my case reverting to older version worked.